# Autofill with VBA (Extending formulas when a new export is imported)

Tags: excel, vba

Situation is as following. Importing a big export trough OLEDB-connection. First 40 columns is Export, next 10 columns contain helping formulas.

On opening I would like it to use Auto-fill to copy down the formulas, so they hit everything on the fresh export.

Code that I currently try to use is of very low quality (recorded macro), which is not professional at all, but I'm trying to learn how to set this up from scratch without recording.

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("DumpFollowUp").Select
Range("AT128432").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AT128512:BN128787")
Range("AT128512:BN128787").Select
End Sub
```

So as said above, Columns AT untill BN contain the formulas i need to extent. Will be using this macro in the Open Workbook Event, after the refresh, so it extends correctly (having loaded the new export).

Comment: To picture this: Does your data (for example) sit in `A1:AN100`, and your formulas in `AT1:BN1`? And you now would like the formulas to be in `AT1:BN100`?

Comment: I believe if you had your OLEDB data land into a Table, then the formulas would Autofill down to the last row of data automatically...

Comment: @Xabier, Thought that would be the point to. It is in a table, but doesn't autofill.

Comment: @JvdV Data is in A:AN, indeed. Formulas in AT:BN (filled down untill the last export), but not the new one.

Comment: You know AT:BN is more than 10 columns of formulas?

Comment: @JvdV, agreed. It's more like 20 columns ^^. Wrong estimation of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help you, I simply removed any Select statements:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DumpFollowUp")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
LastFormula = ws.Cells(1, "AT").End(xlDown).Row
'get the last row with formulas on Column AT
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastFormula, "AT"), ws.Cells(LastRow, "BN")).FillDown
'fill down from LastFormula to the last row with data
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect for what it was meant to do. Only problem I seem to have now is the filling to start from AT2/BN2, since i have column headers. 

How would I go and establish that with your code?

Comment: @RobExcel I've amended the code to fill down from the last row with a formula, should work as expected if you try again... :)

Comment: Hmmm, keep getting an error on the ws.range line (Method Autofill of class Range failed). Any clue?

Comment: Think I found the problem running it. LastRow returns a correct value, while LastFormula returns the same value (column isn't filled with any formula). Both return rownumber 128788. Will run a seperate column and let LastFormula look at that!

Comment: Seperate column Isn't the solution either. LastFormula seems to interpret a table cell which is empty as a value. Any clue how to work around this one, @Xabier ?

Comment: I've updated the code, maybe by changing xlUp to xlDown from the top we can get the last row with any formula in it...

Comment: this works! LastFormula and LastRow get the right values now. But now it's throwing the Method Autofill of class Range error (and i fixed the xLdown in the code;p). Any clue why it's throwing that. Feel like I'm so close to a viable solution.

Comment: @Xabier. Dancing in the office right now. Thank you so much for your dedication.